# onClick function is not being invoked in Google App scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a script that can send emails to the selected people in which the checkbox is set to true and I'm creating custom sidebar for it. I have made the script successfully. But the sidebar is not working I have tried everything like creating an eventListner or adding a `onClick` event but still my function is not invoked I have checked in logs it is not invoking at all. Please could anyone tell what's wrong with my code?

This is my HTML file

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="enter-subject">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enter-subject" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Subject">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="enter-message">Message</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enter-message" placeholder="Enter Message">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="mainButton" onClick="afterButtonIsClicked">Submit</button><!-- 
 onClick="afterButtonIsClicked();" -->
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function afterButtonIsClicked(){
      var subject = document.getElementById("enter-subject")
      var message = document.getElementById("enter-message")
      var rowData = {subject: subject.value, message: message.value}
      console.log(rowData)
      google.script.run.addNewRow(rowData)
    }
    
//    document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListner("click",afterButtonIsClicked)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my script file

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastColumn(),sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var checkbox1 =row[1];
    var emailAddress = row[0];
//    var subject = "test subject";     
//    var message = "test message";    
    if(checkbox1) { 
      console.log(`${rowData.subject} ${rowData.message}`)
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,rowData.subject,rowData.message)
    }
  }
}
```

this is my UI for sidebar file

```
function loadForm() {
  const htmlForSidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
  const htmlOutput = htmlForSidebar.evaluate()
  
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput)
}

function createMenu() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu("My Form")
  menu.addItem("Show Form", "loadForm")
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  createMenu()
}
```

Could anyone diagnose and tell me the error?

Comment: What do you mean by "sidebar is not working"? What is the specific thing you are trying to solve? There's a lot of code and the question is a little vague.

Comment: Questions looking for debugging help should include a [mcve].

Comment: @dimiguel Okay sorry for that, This is my first time asking something on StackOverflow, I was not knowing the question framing policy and my native language is also not English So it's kinda messed up. But for sure I'll take care next time.

Answer (score 4):

This should fix the onClick issue:

```
onClick="afterButtonIsClicked();"
```